# Three things I don't understand in dart - could you explain?

Tags: dart

I am new to dart and these are three situations which I face quite often in my code.
Can anyone explain why those errors are not detected before even running the code?
Is there any "strict" flag to make dart... more "strict" :)?.
Any advices on how to avoid such mistakes?

Sorry for grouping these examples in one question but those are more frequent since I started using dart (flutter actually).

```dart
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  exampleA();
  // exampleB();
  // exampleC();
}

exampleA() {
  final File file = File('file.txt');
  final String text = file != null ? file : 'abc'; // no "compilation error", no error in VS Code
  // Unhandled exception:
  // type '_File' is not a subtype of type 'String'
}

exampleB() {
  void acceptList(List<int> list) {}
  final List<int> list = [1, 2, 3].map((el) => el);
  acceptList(list); // no "compilation error", no error in VS Code
  // Unhandled exception:
  // type 'MappedListIterable<int, int>' is not a subtype of type 'List<int>'
}

// example C
// following example leads to `dynamic` type "leaking" fro class method
class MyClass {
  myMethod () { // VS Code says it's "dynamic myMethod()" - is it so hard to guess return type here? 
    return '';
  }
}

exampleC() {
  final File file = MyClass().myMethod();
  // Unhandled exception:
  // type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'File'
}

// on the other hand
final myClosure = () { // VS Code says it's "String Function() myClosure" so it guessed type here
  return 'sdf'; 
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both example A and B will become errors in the next version (2.12) of Dart.

Along with introducing Null Safety, version 2.12 also removes "implicit downcasts", which is what allows you to assign an `Iterable` to `List` variable, and what allows you to assign "either a `String` or a `File`" (which is then combined to mean "any `Object`") to a `String` variable. You have to opt in to Null Safety to get this feature (but you should anyway).

The `MyClass.myMethod` having `dynamic` as return type is something you have to act to avoid. You can just write the return type `String`, and that'll fix it.
Or you can [enable](https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options#enabling-additional-type-checks) the "no implicit dynamic" extra warning in the analyzer, then it should (I think!) warn you here ... and then you can write `String`.

The reason that the `myClosure` gets a return type inferred and `MyClass.myMethod` does not, is that Dart type inference relies on classes being fully typed before it can start typing expressions. That avoids some risks of cyclic dependencies in the inference (or minimizes them, at least). That also means that a class method declaration can't get its type from its body, so you have to explicitly type your instance methods. (There are some exceptions around variables too, but in general, write the types for your public API).